# Get all subdocuments using Mongoid / Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a document structure in MongoDB like this:

```
User
 |---> Posts
        |----> Comments
```

So, a parent document `User` with a collection of embedded `Post` documents, which itself has a collection of embedded `Comment` documents.

I grab the `User` document back and now have the entire document tree in memory, like so:

```
user = User.where(username: 'test').first
```

From `user` how can I get a list of all the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
user.posts.map{|p| p.comments}.flatten
```

Or

```
user.posts.flat_map(&:comments)
```

Comment: Thanks – I had to change it to `user.posts.map {|p| p.comments}.flatten`, and that now works as expected.

Comment: @Martin: yes, sorry, that was my bad. But I'm glad it helped :-)

Comment: You can do: `user.posts.map(&:comments).flatten`

Comment: Do you know how can I make `flatten`, and still 'query' the result? in flatten we get the results as array, so it failed `undefined method where for #<Array:0xd790664>`

Comment: @user2503775: you'd have to go another way: `Comment.where(:post_id.in => [user.posts.distinct(:id)]).where(...)`

Comment: Note - we can remove the [ ] `Comment.where(:post_id.in => user.posts.distinct(:id)).where(...)`

Comment: @user2503775: right, I originally was going to put a `[...]` there :)